# Shortcut Keys in Diigo Sidebar?

Tags: firefox, diigo, browser-addons

When I used to use the del.icio.us sidebar, you could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and it would appear. Does the diigo sidebar have a similar shortcut key to make it appear and disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for opening the diigolet sidebar appears to be disabled by default, so you if you open about:config and search for "extensions.diigotb.keys.sidebar"

set enabled to true;
extensions.diigotb.keys.sidebar.enabled = true

then control-alt-s can be used to open and close the diigolet sidebar

extensions.diigotb.keys.sidebar.keys = control+alt+s

[image]